# Kotlin initializing an object

Tags: java, android, jvm, kotlin

I have a base class that I am extending, but want to inflate a view where the normal `Java` constructor would be.

```
class TextView(context: Context?) : ViewAbstractClass(context)
```

I am not sure how to do this in `Kotlin`. What are the constructs are there `Kotlin` that allow you to do complex initialisation of objects?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple ways this can be done, however this is what I've been doing in my app.

```
class TextView : ViewAbstractClass {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet) : super(context, attributeSet)
    constructor(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attributeSet, defStyleAttr) {
        // custom init code for this constructor.
    }
    constructor(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int, defStyleRes: Int) : super(context, attributeSet, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)

    init {
        // Common init code
    }

}
```

Notice that you don't actually use `()` in the class signature, but instead provide all the constructors explicitly.

You can learn more about secondary constructors here:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html

Comment: this is a very peculiar piece of kotlin code. Not sure how it answers the Q

Comment: Is there a way to call `super` at different stages of initialisation? Like with the `init` mechanism ... can we call one of these other constructors at some stage during init? Or is init called after the `default` constructors have finished?

Comment: I just realized what he was actually asking. Crap. Yes, as `voddan` stated above, you're looking for `init`. `init` is always called after the parent's `init` and you do not need to call super (actually, you can not).

Comment: you can adjust the A to reflect the Q, or just delete it and make a fresh one

Comment: @bclymer off-topic: if the code above is in your app, something is very wrong with either kotlin or the app. In any way we (community or just me) may discuss that on the slack channel.

Answer (score 2):

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors

```
class Customer(name: String) {
    init {
        logger.info("Customer initialized with value ${name}")
    }
}
```

Comment: How does the `init` code block relate to the `standard` constructors? Example ... can we set name after the `init` code block has run ... or can we call `default` constructors at the end of the `init` code block?

Comment: Think of the init block at the body of the default constructor. So you won't set name, you'll get name passed it.